# Game scene stuck in loading page. Main game scene is not loading

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Console log image

[image]

I am working on a project which is actually in android . Now i have converted it into webgl. Webgl build smoothly works on unity editor but when I am checking it into browser it's only loaded the game loading scene. Main game play scene is not working. My project use addressable for loading the game assets. i have attached the browser console log and home screen screen shot ..

Loading page image

[image]

i want to remove those error and make the game as smooth as in editor

Comment: Do you get any errors when running the game from the unity editor?

Comment: I would probably start digging into that `Initialize err` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` .. I suspect something you are using doesn't support WebGL and the both errors are related as that something checks on which platform it is running and fails as WebGL is not one of the known supported ones ... If you click on that little error on the left you should see the stacktrace .. if you don't make a [development build that includes stacktraces and debugging symbols](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html)

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/argumentoutofrangeexception.1491511/ For the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.. i  have found this document only. But there is no solution at all. Everyone is facing the same issue. Something related to IndexDB. i have applied the targetframe rate to 30 fps . But nothing is changing. It's giving me same result @derHugo